# How to get the pointer of a method inside an object?

Tags: delphi

I have a method named `JsSetCallback`, which is defined as such:

```
function JsSetCallback(Instance: JsValueRef; const CallbackName: UnicodeString; Callback: JsNativeFunction; CallbackState: Pointer; UseStrictRules: Boolean = True): JsValueRef;
```

For its third parameter, I must specify a `JsNativeFunction` callback, which is defined as such:

```
type
  JsNativeFunction = function(callee: JsValueRef; isConstructCall: bool; arguments: PJsValueRef; argumentCount: Word; callbackState: Pointer): JsValueRef; stdcall;
```

Now, let's say I  have a `JsNativeFunction` method called `Window_Atob` and let's say I want it to be the third argument of the `JsSetCallback` method. I would write:

```
function Window_Atob(Callee: JsValueRef; IsConstructCall: bool; Args: PJsValueRefArray; ArgCount: Word; CallbackState: Pointer): JsValueRef; stdcall;
begin
  // ...
end;

JsSetCallback(JsCreateObject, 'atob', @Window_Atob, nil);
```

And everything would work fine. Now, let's say that `Window_Atob` is part of a class, like so:

```
type
  TTestObject = class(TObject)
  public
    function Window_Atob(Callee: JsValueRef; IsConstructCall: bool; Args: PJsValueRefArray; ArgCount: Word; CallbackState: Pointer): JsValueRef; stdcall;
  end;

function TTestObject.Window_Atob(Callee: JsValueRef; IsConstructCall: bool; Args: PJsValueRefArray; ArgCount: Word; CallbackState: Pointer): JsValueRef; stdcall;
begin
  // ...
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TestObject := TTestObject.Create;
  JsSetCallback(JsCreateObject, 'atob', @TestObject.Window_Atob, nil);
  TestObject.Free;
end;
```

Such a call will fail on line 15 with the following compiler error: `E2036 Variable required`. This error is triggered by my call to `@TestObject.Window_Atob`.

[Embarcadero defines this compiler error](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Alexandria/en/E2036_Variable_required_(Delphi)) as "when you try to take the address of an expression or a constant." However, I'm not sure how to solve the problem. Is it possible to get the pointer address of the `Window_Atob` method if it's in a object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JsSetCallback()` expects a standalone function, not a class method.  You cannot use a non-static class method, as it has a hidden `Self` parameter which `JsNativeFunction` does not account for.

So, you can either use a standalone function, or use a static class method (as demonstrated in [Andreas Rejbrand's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77288121/65863).

However, there is another option.  It appears that `JsSetCallback()` has a user-defined `CallbackState` parameter that gets passed into the callback function.  If so, then you can use a proxy function as the callback, passing your object pointer into the proxy, and then the proxy can call your class method on the object, eg:

```
type
  TTestObject = class(TObject)
  public
    function Window_Atob(Callee: JsValueRef; IsConstructCall: bool; Args: PJsValueRefArray; ArgCount: Word): JsValueRef;
  end;

function TTestObject.Window_Atob(Callee: JsValueRef; IsConstructCall: bool; Args: PJsValueRefArray; ArgCount: Word): JsValueRef;
begin
  // ...
end;

function Window_Atob_proxy(callee: JsValueRef; isConstructCall: bool; arguments: PJsValueRef; argumentCount: Word; callbackState: Pointer): JsValueRef; stdcall;
begin
  Result := TTestObject(callbackState).Window_Atob(JsValueRef, IsConstructCall, Args, ArgCount);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TestObject := TTestObject.Create;
  JsSetCallback(JsCreateObject, 'atob', @Window_Atob_proxy, TestObject);

  // do something that will trigger the callback ...

  // Note that when you are ready to destroy the object,
  // make sure you remove the callback as well so it does
  // not try to access an invalid object reference later...
  JsSetCallback(JsCreateObject, 'atob', nil, nil);

  TestObject.Free;
end;
```

Answer (score 3):

A [method](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Methods_(Delphi)#About_Methods) has a hidden `Self` parameter, which is why you cannot use your `TTestObject.Window_Atob`. It simply has the wrong signature.

If you try to convert `TTestObject.Window_Atob` into a `JsNativeFunction`, you'll get the compiler error "E2009 Incompatible types: 'regular procedure and method pointer'".

Now, the `Self` parameter points to the object (=instance of the class) to which the method belongs (or "operates" on).

If you have a method that doesn't need to be associated with a particular object, you can declare it as a [*class method*](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Methods_(Delphi)#Class_Methods):

```pascal
type
  TTestObject = class(TObject)
  public
    class function Window_Atob(Callee: JsValueRef; ...): JsValueRef; stdcall;
  end;
```

Now it will no longer have a hidden `Self` parameter that points to a particular object. Instead, it will have a hidden `Self` parameter that points to the class itself! Therefore, this method will also have the wrong signature.

But if you declare it as a [*static* class method](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Methods_(Delphi)#Class_Static_Methods), it will not have any hidden parameter at all. Essentially, the method becomes an ordinary procedure or function, but within the scope of the class:

```pascal
type
  TTestObject = class(TObject)
  public
    class function Window_Atob(Callee: JsValueRef; ...): JsValueRef; static; stdcall;
  end;
```

Now `TTestObject.Window_Atob` is compatible with your procedural type.

Obviously, making your method a class method means that you can no longer access `Self` within it. But that is a different story.